# How do you filter WHERE using a count?

Tags: neo4j

Starting with this working query:

```
  MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author:User)
  WHERE post.createdAt > { hotAfter } AND post.text =~ { keyword }
  MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)
  WITH post, author, count(DISTINCT commentAuthor) as participantsCount, count(comment) as commentsCount 
  ORDER BY (participantsCount * commentsCount) DESC
  RETURN collect(post {.*, author, participantsCount, commentsCount})[0..{ LIMIT }] as posts
```

I'd additionally like to filter the posts with number of comments that fit the criteria:

```
WHERE (count(DISTINCT commentAuthor) * count(comment)) <= { someNumber }
```

But I am not sure where/how to apply this logic e.g. this is incorrect:

```
  MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author:User)
  WHERE post.createdAt > { hotAfter } AND post.text =~ { keyword }
  MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)
  WHERE count(DISTINCT commentAuthor) * count(comment) <= 10
  WITH post, author, count(DISTINCT commentAuthor) as participantsCount, count(comment) as commentsCount 
  ORDER BY (participantsCount * commentsCount) DESC
  RETURN collect(post {.*, author, participantsCount, commentsCount})[0..{ LIMIT }] as posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this as a WHERE clause before you do your ORDER BY:

```
MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author:User)
WHERE post.createdAt > { hotAfter } AND post.text =~ { keyword }
MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)
WITH post, author, count(DISTINCT commentAuthor) as participantsCount, count(comment) as commentsCount 
WITH post, author, participantsCount, commentsCount, participantsCount * commentsCount as countProduct
ORDER BY countProduct DESC
WHERE countProduct <= { someNumber }
RETURN collect(post {.*, author, participantsCount, commentsCount})[0..{ LIMIT }]
```

Comment: Hi, actually just tried this out, and the query appears to be invalid.

Comment: `Invalid input 'D' (line 6, column 5 (offset: 308))
"  ORDER BY participantsCount * commentsCount DESC"
     ^`

Comment: Attempted a fix, give it another go.

Comment: Unfortunately getting the same error. It doesn't seem to like the WHERE before ORDER? `Invalid input 'D' (line 7, column 3 (offset: 381))
"ORDER BY countProduct DESC"
   ^`

Comment: Yes, that's it, switching the two avoids the syntax error. I rarely use those two together didn't pick up on the ordering issue.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on the collection at the end seems to work.

```
  MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author:User)
  WHERE post.createdAt > { hotAfter } AND post.text =~ { keyword }
  MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)
  WITH post, author, count(DISTINCT commentAuthor) as participantsCount, count(comment) as commentsCount 
  ORDER BY (participantsCount * commentsCount) DESC
  RETURN filter (
    x in collect(post {.*, author, participantsCount, commentsCount}) 
    WHERE (x.participantsCount * x.commentsCount) <= { someNumber }
  )[0..{ LIMIT }] as posts
```